# fetch html data from website into excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

Object does not support this property or method.

Error occur on this line:

```
For Each ele In objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("table info-table").getElementsByTagName("tr")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName()` returns a *collection* of matching elements (even if there's only one match), so you need something like (e.g.):

```
For Each ele In objIE.document.getElementsByClassName( _
                 "table info-table")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")
```

which will loop over the `tr` elements in the first table with a matching class name.
If you need a different table you'll need to adjust the `(0)`